# 401 Unauthorized on all SocialTables API requests

Tags: api, social-tables

I'm new to the SocialTables API and I seem to do something wrong doing requests against their API.

I've successfully authenticated and got an access token, but all other requests I do against the api returns a 401 Unauthorized response. This goes for my api integration as well as tests done through the API Gateway (https://developer-portal.socialtables.com/api-console)

An example of a request that gives a 401 is:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer MY-ACCESS-TOKEN' 'https://ape.socialtables.com/4.0/events/'
```

I've replaced my real access token with "MY-ACCESS-TOKEN" in the example above.

Response body is:

```
{"code":"UnauthorizedError","message":""}
```

Is there somewhere I need to configure which events the app is allowed to access? Or am I doing something wrong when communicating with the api?

Answer (score 0):

An unauthorized error response may be due to an invalid bearer token (which could have expired or been manually invalidated). You can get information about your bearer token in one of the following ways:

- Paste the bearer token into our API console's `OAuth Bearer Token` field and hover over the green or red indicator which appears to the right of the token.
- Use the `/oauth/token` `GET` endpoint to get information about the bearer token you supply in the `Authorization` header.

As for this particular endpoint, it looks like our docs are in error in that the route should not include a trailing slash, and should use `api.socialtables.com` instead of `ape.socialtables.com`.

Please try again using a new bearer token and the following modified request structure:

`curl -XGET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN' 'https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/events'`.

We'll update the docs as soon as possible to rectify this inconsistency. In the mean time, can you copy the results of the bearer token inspection into this issue?

Comment: Thanks, this seem to get me a bit further, but I still get a 401 Unauthorized when trying to get details about an event.

Does it matter if the oauth/token use the ape or api endpoint? It answers on both. 

Example of 401 issue:



`curl -XGET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer MY-AUTH-TOKEN' 'https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/events/MY-EVENT-ID/users' -i`

Comment: Response:

`HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Mon, 07 Nov 2016 18:44:57 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 41
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Vary: Origin
ST-Request-ID: 92c82094-2d92-41c1-9bc5-b25c4102d0fd#11575117
X-Kong-Upstream-Latency: 144
X-Kong-Proxy-Latency: 0
Via: kong/0.9.1

{"code":"UnauthorizedError","message":""}% `

Comment: When trying to get all events from `curl -XGET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN' 'https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/events'` I get an empty result even though I have events created through the socialtables web app.

Comment: Looks like the events under your account use an older data model, which is only compatible with the `/4.0/legacyvm3` (formerly `/3.0`) endpoint set. Please re-attempt using `/4.0/legacyvm3/events/{eventID}` endpoint.